# How to get latest words from shell-variable without looping through all words?

Tags: shell, sh

I want to get two latest words from a string variable.
Total number of words in the string variable is not constant.

This is what I try:

```
LIST=`some command`
LATEST1=""
LATEST2=""

for ITEM in $LIST
do
  LATEST2="$LATEST1"
  LATEST1="$ITEM"
done

echo "Latest:     $LATEST1"
echo "2nd latest: $LATEST2"
```

But it is slow. Is there any better way to do it?

sh shell of busybox is used. Other scripting languages are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex which will match the last 2 words (including whitespaces in this case)

```
(\s\w+){2}$
```

Comment: +1, this seems to work: 
`echo -n "$LIST" | grep -o -E "(\s\w+){2}$"`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use parameter substitution:

```
words="one two three four"
last=${words##* }
echo $last  # => four
tmp=${words% *}
last2=${tmp##* }
echo $last2  # => three
```

Comment: +1, This works nice, and it uses only internal stuff of sh. Maybe the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -e 'hello world\nhow are you' | 
tr '\n' ' ' | 
awk '
END{if(NF>1)printf("Latest:\t\t%s\n2nd latest:\t%s\n", $NF, $(NF-1)); else print "ERROR"}'
Latest:         you
2nd latest:     are
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a purely shell way using something like this:

```
words="one two three four"

words=($words)

echo ${words[${#words}]}            # prints 'four'
echo ${words[((${#words} - 1))]}    # prints 'three'
```

This works by assigning the variable containing the strings into an array and then accessing it by key.

Comment: This would be great. But arrays are not supported by sh. Arrays seems to be supported by newer versions of bash.